# phpcs: How to ignore Drupal's 80 char line length limit

Tags: coding-standards

I want to use PHP CodeSniffer with the default `Drupal` and `DrupalPractice` rulesets to check my custom modules. But I definitly don't want the 80 char line length limit, and phpcs is spamming the report with those warnings. I've created a phpcs.xml in my project root (taken from this [blog](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/drupal-9-using-phpcodesniffer-inspect-custom-code))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset name="my_drupal10_phpcs_configuration">

  <rule ref="Drupal"/>
  <rule ref="DrupalPractice"/>

  <arg name="extensions" value="php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,css,info,txt,md,yml"/>

  <exclude-pattern>*/.git/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/.vscode/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/.idea/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/bower_components/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/node_modules/*</exclude-pattern>
  <!--Exclude third party code.-->
  <exclude-pattern>*/vendor/*</exclude-pattern>

  <file>./web/modules/custom</file>
  <file>./web/themes/custom</file>

  <!-- MY CHANGE: Ignore the 80char line length limit. -->
  <rule ref="Generic.Files.LineLength">
    <properties>
      <property name="lineLimit" value="120"/>
      <property name="absoluteLineLimit" value="0"/>
    </properties>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

but I still get spammed by messages like

```
 180 | WARNING | Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 141 characters
 187 | WARNING | Line exceeds 80 characters; contains 105 characters
```

How can I override Drupal's 80 chars with a soft limit of 120 chars?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was copy&pasting the rule into the root tag. To override the Drupal ruleset, all those overrides have to be nested. My working phpcs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset name="drupal10_phpcs_configuration">

  <!-- Use Drupal and DrupalPractice standards. -->
  <!-- CUSTOM OVERRIDES NEED TO GO INSIDE THIS TAG -->
  <rule ref="Drupal">
    <!-- Ignore "Missing file doc comment" errors. -->
    <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FileComment.Missing"/>

    <!-- Don't check line length in text files at all. -->
    <exclude name="Drupal.Files.TxtFileLineLength.TooLong"/>

    <!-- Change the line length limit to 120 chars. -->
    <properties>
      <property name="lineLimit" value="120"/>
      <property name="absoluteLineLimit" value="0"/>
    </properties>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="DrupalPractice"/>

  <!-- Inluce the extensions of the files we want to test. -->
  <arg name="extensions" value="php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,css,info,txt,yml,md"/>

  <!--Exclude folders used by common frontend tools. These folders match the file_scan_ignore_directories setting in default.settings.php-->
  <exclude-pattern>*/.git/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/.vscode/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/.idea/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/bower_components/*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>*/node_modules/*</exclude-pattern>
  <!--Exclude third party code.-->
  <exclude-pattern>*/vendor/*</exclude-pattern>

  <!-- Inspect the following directories. -->
  <file>./web/modules/custom</file>
  <file>./web/themes/custom</file>
</ruleset>
```